# What is the right type of file for server side includes

Tags: html, ssi

I have been coding a website using html and css. To improve my website and to be more efficient, I have been trying to incorporate server side includes for my header, nabber, content section, and footer. I have researched many different ways to do this. I have come up with this so far:

```
<!-- #include virtual="../includes/navbar.txt" -->
<!--#include virtual="../includes/content.txt"-->
<!--include virtual="../includes/footer.txt"-->
<!-- #include virtual="../includes/header.txt" -->
```

With the proper syntax of the exclamation point and all that.

This does not work when testing using MAMP or any other tester.
Is there a different type of file that would work when using SSI's instead of .txt? Thank you!

Comment: Server-side includes are platform dependent.  Whether they're supported and how you do them depend on the web server software you're using and how it's configured.  It's feature of the web server and not HTML.

Comment: So how could I find out what type of SSI's are right for Apache server? Thanks!

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html I'd start there.

Comment: Thanks Ill check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file extension of the file containing SSI code is `.shtml`.

You can leave the included files as `.txt`.